# Clone Github Repo Using Slurm

Tags: slurm

I need to clone data from a github repository to storage on a computational cluster using slurm. What commands would I need to do this, and would I need to create a script for this or can it be done from the command line?

Comment: Probably that's a question better to be directed to your cluster admin. In all likelihood slurm will not be involved in `git clone`. Does simple `git clone [repourl]` command work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `srun`, as in

```
srun git clone <repository> [<output/directory>]
```

where you would need to adjust `<repository>` to the server and repository you like to clone. If you need to clone to a specific directory, adjust and supply `<output/directory>`.